# Accessing External custom IP port from kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm having a microservice architecture and one of my services needs to access some specific IP `(3.*.*.*:63815)` to connect WebSocket. So from the provider side, I have whitelist my ingress External IP.

But when I tried to connect, the connection is not established.

Do I need to update any firewall rules or add custom IP/Port access inside via Ingress?

Any help on this will be appreciated!

Edit:

1. I'm using GCP Cloud for this
2. I need to connect a external FIXapi client from the POD

Comment: Are you sure your external IP is detected as `ingress External IP`? How exactly packets flow from inside the pod to the external network?

Comment: @zerkms I'm not sure about it.  Please suggest which ip is used for whitlisting

Comment: Use the IP that your pods are seen from the external network.

Comment: Most probably you will need to whitelist the IP address of the nodes that your pods are running on

Comment: Hello, I have difficulties to understand your question. Please edit your question to include: 1. In which way the communication should happen (if it's incoming or outgoing traffic from a `Pod`), 2. Please specify which cloud provider are you using. 3. If it's feasible please attach the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DawidKruk I have updated the Question, Let me know if you want information

Comment: @MuthuKumar I've provided an answer for your question. Please take a look and let me know if you have questions/concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I need to agree and give more visibility to the comment made by user @dishant makwana:

> Most probably you will need to whitelist the IP address of the nodes that your pods are running on

Assuming that you want to send a request from your `GKE` `Pod` to a service located outside of your `project`/`organization`/`GCP`, **you should allow the traffic on your "on-premise" location from your `GCP` resources.**

The source IP of the traffic that you are creating could be either:

- `GKE` Node**s** External IP address**es** - if the cluster **is not created private**.
- `Cloud NAT` IP address - if you've configured `Cloud NAT` for your **private** cluster.

> A side note!
>
> If you haven't created a `Cloud NAT` for your **private** cluster, you won't be able to reach external sources.

---

Answering following question:

> Do I need to update any firewall rules or add custom IP/Port access inside via Ingress?

If we are speaking about `GKE`/`GCP` environment then, no. You don't need to modify any firewall rules from `GCP` side (assuming that you haven't reconfigured your firewall rules in any way).

`Ingress` resource (not rule) in `Kubernetes`/`GKE` is used to expose your own application to the external access (it's for inbound traffic, not outbound).

Citing the official documentation:

> #### Implied rules
>
> Every VPC network has two implied firewall rules. These rules exist, but are not shown in the Cloud Console:
>
> **Implied allow egress rule**. An egress rule whose action is `allow`, destination is `0.0.0.0/0`, and priority is the lowest possible (`65535`) lets any instance send traffic to any destination, except for traffic [blocked](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic) by Google Cloud. A higher priority firewall rule may restrict outbound access. Internet access is allowed if no other firewall rules deny outbound traffic and if the instance has an external IP address or uses a Cloud NAT instance. For more information, see [Internet access requirements](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#internet_access_reqs).
>
> **Implied deny ingress rule**. An ingress rule whose action is `deny`, source is `0.0.0.0/0`, and priority is the lowest possible (`65535`) protects all instances by blocking incoming connections to them. A higher priority rule might allow incoming access. The default network includes some [additional rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc) that override this one, allowing certain types of incoming connections.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: VPC: Docs: Firewall: Default firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: NAT: Docs: GKE example](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)*